svg foreignObject not showing properly in Safari
I have the problem that my svg foreignObject not showing properly in Safari. I tried it already with clip-path on the video element to show it properly but it also doesn't work like expected. Does anyone have a solution to make it properly for Safari?
Here is how it looks in Chrome:

And here how it looks on Safari:

Here is my code:


    .clip-path-video-small {
        position: relative;
        clip-path: polygon(40% 0%, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 50%);
        height: 100%;

        video {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            z-index: -1;
            width: auto;
            margin: auto;
        }
    }
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 355 740" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
            <div class="clip-path-video-small">
                <video autoplay loop width="100%" height="100%"
                    src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"></video>
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
        <path
            d="M140.928 17.5996L141.068 17.8695H141.372H342.178L353.826 36.777V274.737L346.083 278.023L345.778 278.152V278.483V595.983V596.242L345.989 596.391L354.5 602.425V716.016L340.536 739.5H150.42L137.586 715.915L137.444 715.654H137.146H20.0453L1.71289 688.953V475.911L6.92563 468.297L7.01307 468.17V468.015V244.196V243.996L6.87527 243.851L0.798385 237.465L0.79834 17.5994L20.7277 0.5H132.068L140.928 17.5996Z"
            fill="url(#pattern0_151_6563)" />
        <path
            d="M140.928 17.5996L141.068 17.8695H141.372H342.178L353.826 36.777V274.737L346.083 278.023L345.778 278.152V278.483V595.983V596.242L345.989 596.391L354.5 602.425V716.016L340.536 739.5H150.42L137.586 715.915L137.444 715.654H137.146H20.0453L1.71289 688.953V475.911L6.92563 468.297L7.01307 468.17V468.015V244.196V243.996L6.87527 243.851L0.798385 237.465L0.79834 17.5994L20.7277 0.5H132.068L140.928 17.5996Z"
            fill="url(#paint0_linear_151_6563)" />
        <path
            d="M140.928 17.5996L141.068 17.8695H141.372H342.178L353.826 36.777V274.737L346.083 278.023L345.778 278.152V278.483V595.983V596.242L345.989 596.391L354.5 602.425V716.016L340.536 739.5H150.42L137.586 715.915L137.444 715.654H137.146H20.0453L1.71289 688.953V475.911L6.92563 468.297L7.01307 468.17V468.015V244.196V243.996L6.87527 243.851L0.798385 237.465L0.79834 17.5994L20.7277 0.5H132.068L140.928 17.5996Z"
            stroke="url(#paint1_linear_151_6563)" />
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <path
                    d="M0.327 0.024L0.328 0.025H0.329H0.798L0.825 0.051V0.384L0.808 0.389L0.807 0.390V0.391V0.839V0.840L0.806 0.840L0.826 0.849V1H0.793L0.674 0.994L0.653 0.962L0.652 0.961H0.652H0.096L0.008 0.926V0.639L0.025 0.628L0.025 0.628V0.325V0.325L0.024 0.324L0.002 0.317L0.002 0.024L0.052 0H0.330L0.327 0.024Z" />
            </clipPath>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_151_6563" x1="177.5" y1="462.652" x2="177.5" y2="770"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-opacity="0" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.62" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_151_6563" x1="177.649" y1="0" x2="177.649" y2="740"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop stop-color="#5C7291" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#5C7291" stop-opacity="0" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path
            d="M140.928 17.5996L141.068 17.8695H141.372H342.178L353.826 36.777V274.737L346.083 278.023L345.778 278.152V278.483V595.983V596.242L345.989 596.391L354.5 602.425V716.016L340.536 739.5H150.42L137.586 715.915L137.444 715.654H137.146H20.0453L1.71289 688.953V475.911L6.92563 468.297L7.01307 468.17V468.015V244.196V243.996L6.87527 243.851L0.798385 237.465L0.79834 17.5994L20.7277 0.5H132.068L140.928 17.5996Z"
            fill="url(#pattern0_151_6563)" />
        <foreignObject height="100%" width="90%" y="5%" x="5%" [style]="{
            '--primary-color': this.environment.settings[this.environment.landingType].loaderColorActive,
            '--second-color': this.environment.settings[this.environment.landingType].secondColor,
            '--loader-color': this.environment.settings[this.environment.landingType].loaderColor
        }">
            <div class="text-container mobile" style="text-align: center">
                <div innerHTML="{{'HEROSECTIONTITLE_' + environment.landingType| translate}}"></div>
                <div innerHTML="{{'HEROSECTIONBODY_' + environment.landingType | translate}}"></div>
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
    </svg>



This is my code how I tried to solve the problem. Does anyone have a solution to make it properly in Safari?

Try to add attribute xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" to the <video> element. Interpreting elements without a namespace as HTML is only required in the SVG 2 spec. I can't test myself, but maybe Safari is still handling this according to SVG 1.1.

And please, do not post code as a snippet if it is not executable. If you do not want to provide links to your assets, try to find a [mcve] that can be used for testing.

sorry fot that. the video is now visible but my problem now is that my video with mask-image doesn´t stretch to full width on safari

i did an update from my code
